# Export a simple Dictionary into Excel file in python

Tags: python, dictionary, excel-2010

I am new to python.
I have a simple dictionary for which the key and values are as follows

```
dict1 = {"number of storage arrays": 45, "number of ports":2390,......}
```

i need to get them in a excel sheet as follows

```
number of storage arrays 45
number of ports          2390
```

I have a very big dictionary.

Comment: Just export it to CSV using the `csv` module, and then import it into Excel. File - Save As in Excel to save it as `.xlsx`

Answer (score 28):

You can use pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

dict1 = {"number of storage arrays": 45, "number of ports":2390}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=dict1, index=[0])

df = (df.T)

print (df)

df.to_excel('dict1.xlsx')
```

Comment: what if I want to append similar data in same excel file

Answer (score 14):

This will write the contents of the dictionary to `output.csv`. The first column will contain the keys, the second will contain the values.

```
import csv

with open('output.csv', 'w') as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output)
    for key, value in dict1.items():
        writer.writerow([key, value])
```

You can open the csv with excel and save it to any format you'd like.

Comment: brilliant idea, should use `dict1.items()` on py3

Comment: Use "w+" instead of "wb" to be able to create a new file and not just write bytes

Comment: Use only "w" in with open('output.csv', 'w') as output:

Answer (score 0):

As an extension to *@Daniel Timberlake*'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28555411/10237506), here's what I found worked for me. I simply wanted to save a list of `dict` object (rows) to a CSV file, which could then later be converted to **.xlsx** format if needed.

```py
from __future__ import annotations  # optional on Python 3.9+

from csv import DictWriter

def write_to_csv(rows: list[dict]):
    with open('./output.csv', 'w') as output:
        writer = DictWriter(output, fieldnames=rows[0].keys())
        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerows(rows)
```