# Writing dictionary to multiple columns in csv file in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a dictionary to csv file in python.

I'm using following solution:

[Export a simple Dictionary into Excel file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28555112/export-a-simple-dictionary-into-excel-file-in-python)

However when i write to file in a following manner:

```
for key, value in dict1.iteritems():
    writer.writerow([key, value])
```

The key and the value from dictionary are stored in single column for each item in dictionary. I would like key to be stored in first column and value to be stored in second column and to assign headers to the columns if possible. Can anyone help?

Comment: Please show how you open the file and define `writer`. Is it identical to the linked question?

Comment: can you show a fragment of the result csv file?

Comment: Let me make sure I understand.  You have just one dictionary with many items.  You want to store it in two columns with the first column containing the keys and the second column containing the values, correct?

Comment: Further to my comment - I cannot replicate this issue. I think the possible errors are; you're defining a file extension other than `.csv` and Excel is opening it (I tried `.xlsx` but Excel says the file is corrupt so I'm not sure about this one) or you've defined `writer` to use a different delimiter e.g. `;` which Excel is not configured to read, or you've changed the standard delimiter in Excel so that it isn't recognising `,`.

Comment: Thank you for you're replies. It turned out that you were right! Excel was configured to use tab as a delimiter and not a comma! It works well after all.

Answer (score 1):

You can do as follows using **pandas** :

```
import pandas as pd

dic = #your dictionnary
# Creating your dataframe from your dictionnary
df = pd.DataFrame([(k, v) for k, v in dic.iteritems()], columns=['key', 'value'])
# Store the data into a csv file
df.to_csv('your_path', sep=',') # indicate the path where to store the csv file
```