# Write Python dictionary to file

Tags: python, excel, get

I've been trying to understand how to work with Website APIs and how to use get methods to download data from the website.

At the moment I have a big dictionary that I'm trying to write to file.

When I output it to a file it looks like this:

```
 {"Tickets":[{"Project":"Test_Project", "TicketID":"1", "Title":"Title_1", "Reportedby":"User_1"},{"Project":"Test_Project", "TicketID":"2", "Title":"Title_2", "Reportedby":"User_2"}]}
```

How can I output this to a Excel file?

I've tried using all kinds of string formatting, like:

```
response_string = response_string[response_string.find("["):len(response_string)-1]
response_string = response_string[1:len(response_string)-1]
response_string = response_string.replace("},{","} , {")
response_array = response_string.split(" , ") + response_array
```

but I know this is not the right way as a comma inside of the text would really mess this up.

Thanks,
A.

Comment: Perhaps create a pandas dataframe and save as excel/csv?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Export a simple Dictionary into Excel file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28555112/export-a-simple-dictionary-into-excel-file-in-python)

Comment: The best thing is to use Pandas DataFrame and then save it to excel. But if you would not like to use it this may be helping you. https://pythonspot.com/save-a-dictionary-to-a-file/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Dictionary to CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8331469/python-dictionary-to-csv)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to save a dictionary to a csv file, the basic method is to use the csv module. The assumption is that you have a list of dictionaries, with keys as the column names and values you want to save.

```
import csv

data = {"Tickets":[{"Project":"Test_Project", "TicketID":"1", "Title":"Title_1", "Reportedby":"User_1"},{"Project":"Test_Project", "TicketID":"2", "Title":"Title_2", "Reportedby":"User_2"}]}

#Write a CSV file. 
f = open('temp','w')
c = csv.DictWriter(f,data['Tickets'][0].keys())
c.writeheader()
c.writerows(data['Tickets'])
f.close()

#Read a CSV file. 
f = open('temp','r')
c = csv.DictReader(f)
data = {'Tickets':list(c)}
f.close()
```

Comment: This seems like what I'm looking for but is there any way to write to .xlsx instead of .csv?

Comment: Not really, a CSV file has nothing to do with excel. It is a Comma-Separated-Values file. Excel opens this with ease. In excel, covert the file to an xlsx, by choosing save-as. The main difference is that CSV can be opened with any editor and read easily because it is stings and commas, but a xlsx file is a collection of compressed XML files used by Microsoft products. Try to open an .xlsx file with an editor like notepad or gedit.

Comment: There could be some module out there that knows how to create the compressed stacks of XML files for a xlsx format. But I don't know off the top of my head.

Answer (score 1):

A much easier way to save dictionaries or any other files is joblib from sklearn.externals.

You can do this there in a single line.

`joblib.dump('filename', dict_name)`

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html