# python - bag of words

Tags: python, dataframe, word-count

I want to create a very simple bag of words based on multiple Excel-files (300).

DummyDoc1 = "This is a testdoc

DummyDoc2 = "This is also a testdoc, the second one"

...

I can import all the files and I also can do a simple wordcount (dict) for each file.
What I don't get is how to combine those two in a matrix that looks something like this.

[image]

Code importing files:

```
def get_files(dir):
    files = [f.path for f in os.scandir(dir)]
    return files

files = get_files_ext(DIR_IN, "xlsx")

for file in files:
    file = fm.get_filename(file)
    df_all = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(DIR_IN, file))
```

Code wordcount:

```
text = open(r"..\PycharmProjects\DrillPinsBagOfWords\files_in\test.csv", "r", errors="ignore")

d = dict()
for line in text:
    
    line = line.strip()
    line = line.lower()
    words = line.split(" ")
    for word in words:
        if word in d:
            d[word] = d[word] + 1
        else:
            d[word] = 1


gesorteerd = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

for x in gesorteerd:
     print(x)
```

Can someone give me some direction please?

================================================================

Here is the code I have so far.  I'm still struggeling with the total dict.

```
import filemanager as fm
import pandas as pd

directory = r"C:\Users\files_in_test"

total_dict = dict()
files = fm.get_files_ext(directory, "csv")

count = 0
list_dict = []
for filename in files:
    d = dict()
    with open(filename, "r", errors="ignore") as text:
        count += 1
        for line in text:
            line = line.strip()
            line = line.lower()
            words = line.split(" ")
            for word in words:
                if word in d:
                    d[word] = d[word] + 1
                else:
                    d[word] = 1
    print("Print dict", count, d)
    # maak lijst van dict's
    list_dict.append(d.copy())

# print lijst van dict's
print("Print list_dict: ", list_dict)

df = pd.DataFrame(list_dict)
print(df)

result = df.transpose()
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Get all those excel files into one directory
- Iterate over all files in that directory
- Use the code from your `wordcount` to count words in every file

Use [this source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28555112/export-a-simple-dictionary-into-excel-file-in-python) to export into excel format

```
import os

total = dict()
directory = "YOUR DIRECTORY HERE"
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
   d = dict()
   with open(filename, "r") as text:
     for line in text:
    
      line = line.strip()
      line = line.lower()
      words = line.split(" ")
      for word in words:
          if word in d:
              d[word] = d[word] + 1
          else:
              d[word] = 1
    total[filename] = d


gesorteerd = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

for x in gesorteerd:
     print(x)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response: now I have the total bag of words for all the files.
How do I make the matrix represenation, each dict (per file) and the total dict combined?